# change user control size automatically in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, size

I have a user control that there is some buttons in it.
when I use the user control in another project, it's buttons will resize automatically. It happend just in special form that I think no important property change.

for example my user control size is 700 px and its buttons size are 80px.
when I use the user control in another project, the user control size is 700 but the buttons size will be change to 120px so some buttons be hidden.

do you have any idea for this problem? thanks...

Comment: Windows forms or asp.net web form?

Comment: @JaroslavKubacek its windows form

Comment: Look at the two forms' resize events. One will scale the UC including its child controls, i.e. the buttons, the other doesn't do it at all or does it in a different way. (Scaled down buttons are not really a good thing, though.. In Winforms they almost always look ugly and get unreadable.)

Comment: @TaW there is not any event for the user control and my form. just load event...

Comment: u should minimize the linker to your local awk